# z-index issue in activity page

Tags: bug

In the **Activity Page**, the z-index of the *Next Privilege* tracker seems to have an issue as it is getting displayed on top of the **Recent Achievements** dropdown.

This is a very recent issue. I am not sure if it happened after I reached 2500 reputation (which led to change in the Privilege tracker) or it happened due to a website update.

Clicking on the overlapped element shows the **Privilege dropdown** so it should be an element ordering issue.

[image: Screenshot of the bug]

Comment: This may not be an issue for much longer. The whole top-bar has been redesigned and is rolling out across stackexchange network as we speak. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network